# For class using the `with` keyword in python, can I have it __repr__ (print) itself?

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm trying to create an object that plays nicely with the `with` keyword in Python. I understand that you have to create `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, but I'm not quite sure how manipulate the object. As a concrete example I wrote a class that creates local space to work in, and cleans up on exit:

```
import tempfile, os, shutil
class temp_workspace(object):

    def __enter__(self):
        self.local_dir = os.getcwd()
        self.temp_dir  = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        os.chdir(self.temp_dir)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        os.chdir(self.local_dir)
        shutil.rmtree(self.temp_dir)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.temp_dir
```

This works just fine, but when I try to print the local directory name:

```
with temp_workspace() as T:
    print "Temp directory name is ", T
```

It shows up as `None` and `__repr__` isn't even called! It's really confusing since `T` is also `NoneType`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not returning the object from `__enter__` as specified by the [context manager protocol](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers).  Add `return self` to the end of your `__enter__` method.

Comment: To clarify, in this specific case, the easy solution is to add `return self` to `__enter__`.

Comment: Thanks for the link - is anything that uses the `with` statement considered a context manager?

Comment: @Hooked: Yes, "context manager" is the name for the protocol required by the `with` statement.  When you write something that "works with the `with` statement" you are writing a context manager.